# Sqlalchemy : Type geoalchemy2 does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

i am trying to run a migration on postgresql database, i am using python flask.Following error appears:

> type "geometry" does not exists

migration is:

```
    """empty message

Revision ID: a9d0c3e2ac85
Revises: 06493ef33fab
Create Date: 2016-08-28 01:00:41.022063

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'a9d0c3e2ac85'
down_revision = '06493ef33fab'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import geoalchemy2


def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('location', sa.Column('coordinates', geoalchemy2.types.Geometry(geometry_type='POINT'), nullable=True))
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('location', 'coordinates')
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

and my schema is this:

```
import enum
from .extensions import db
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

class Location(db.Model, Entity):
name = db.Column(db.String(30))
coordinates = db.Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?